# upload a new image in canvas without eliminating existing image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, easeljs

I'm trying to create a web design custom made dress. I made ​​it with easel.js. I have a problem when I upload images into the clothes that are on the canvas when the initial functions, image shirt has disappeared ("upload / men_shirt_front.png").

```
function init() {   
        canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        // Enable touch support
        if (createjs.Touch.isSupported()) { createjs.Touch.enable(stage); }
        // create amd draw the branding image for the qr-code
        var Shirt = new Image();
        Shirt.addEventListener('load', function () {
            ctx.drawImage(this, 10, 10, 275, 275);
        },false);
        Shirt.src = "upload/men_shirt_front.png";

    }
```

I know that the real problem is in

```
displayPicture = function (imgPath) {

            var image = new Image();
            image.onload = function () {
                // Create a Bitmap from the loaded image
                var img = new createjs.Bitmap(event.target)

                // scale it
                img.scaleX = img.scaleY = 0.5;

                /// Add to display list
                stage.addChild(img);

                //Enable Drag'n'Drop 
                enableDrag(img);

                // Render Stage
                stage.update(); 
            }
            // Load the image
            image.src = imgPath;
        }
```

I have tried many many ways to change it but I can not. how to upload a new image in canvas without eliminating existing image in initial function?
below is the full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Upload and display images on HTML5 Canvas</title>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">  
    <script src="easeljs-0.5.0.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/upclick-min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/export_canvas/base64.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="libs/export_canvas/canvas2image.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /** Init */
    window.onload = init;
    function init() {   
        canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        // Enable touch support
        if (createjs.Touch.isSupported()) { createjs.Touch.enable(stage); }
        // create amd draw the branding image for the qr-code
        var Shirt = new Image();
        Shirt.addEventListener('load', function () {
            ctx.drawImage(this, 10, 10, 275, 275);
        },false);
        Shirt.src = "upload/men_shirt_front.png";

    }
    /**Export and save the canvas as PNG */
    function exportAndSaveCanvas()  {

        // Get the canvas screenshot as PNG
        var screenshot = Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas, true);

        // This is a little trick to get the SRC attribute from the generated <img> screenshot
        canvas.parentNode.appendChild(screenshot);
        screenshot.id = "canvasimage";      
        data = $('#canvasimage').attr('src');
        canvas.parentNode.removeChild(screenshot);

        // Send the screenshot to PHP to save it on the server
        var url = 'upload/export.php';
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST", 
            url: url,
            dataType: 'text',
            data: {
                base64data : data
            }
        });
    }
    /** Export and display the canvas as PNG in a new window */
    function exportAndView()  {

        var screenshot = Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas, true);
        var win = window.open();
        $(win.document.body).html(screenshot );
    }
</script>
<body onload="init()">
    <div style="position: relative" >
        <input type="button" value="View screenshot in a new page" onClick="exportAndView()" >
        <input type="button" value="Export and Upload Screenshot" onClick="exportAndSaveCanvas()" >
        <input id="uploader" type="button" value="Upload picture from hard disk">       
    </div>
    <canvas width="1000" height="550" id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas;
        var stage;      
        var uploader = document.getElementById('uploader');
        /**
         * UPLOAD SCRIPT 
         * This script uses the upclick-min.js library to upload files on a webserver folder
         * using a PHP script ("upload/upload.php")
         * Project homepage: http://code.google.com/p/upload-at-click/
         */
        upclick(
        {
          element: uploader,
          action: 'upload/upload.php', 
          onstart:
            function(filename)
            {
              //alert('Start upload: '+filename);
            },

        oncomplete:
            function(response_data) 
            {
              // Check upload Status
              if (response_data != "FAIL") {      
                // Draw the picture into Canvas     
                // "response_data" contains the image file name returned from the PHP script
                displayPicture("upload/" + response_data);
                }
            }
        });
        /**
         * Load and display the uploaded picture on CreateJS Stage 
         */
        displayPicture = function (imgPath) {

            var image = new Image();
            image.onload = function () {
                // Create a Bitmap from the loaded image
                var img = new createjs.Bitmap(event.target)

                // scale it
                img.scaleX = img.scaleY = 0.5;

                /// Add to display list
                stage.addChild(img);

                //Enable Drag'n'Drop 
                enableDrag(img);

                // Render Stage
                stage.update(); 
            }
            // Load the image
            image.src = imgPath;
        }
        /**
         * Enable drag'n'drop on DisplayObjects
         */
        enableDrag = function (item) {
            // OnPress event handler
            item.onPress = function(evt) {
                var offset = {  x:item.x-evt.stageX, 
                                y:item.y-evt.stageY};
                // Bring to front
                stage.addChild(item);
                // Mouse Move event handler
                evt.onMouseMove = function(ev) {

                    item.x = ev.stageX+offset.x;
                    item.y = ev.stageY+offset.y;
                    stage.update();
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It's upload script 'upload/upload.php'

```
<?php
$tmp_file_name = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$ok = move_uploaded_file($tmp_file_name, $_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

// This message will be passed to 'oncomplete' function
echo $ok ? $_FILES['Filedata']['name'] : "FAIL";

?>
```

Comment: any particular reason you are mixing EaselJS Bitmaps/Stage with a context.drawImage() call? The drawImage will just be drawn once to the canvas, so any stage updates will clear the canvas before drawing EaselJS children. If you use another Bitmap instance with the stage, both images will be retained, since EaselJS will know how to redraw it.

Comment: because I am just a beginner learners who seek any way html5 on google just to make a custom made shirt website. so if you give me a clue how or I will try it with pleasure :)
so the point I'm swallowing a variety of ways from a variety of sources to make it real